# Why use an adverb to modify a subject?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

> Up close, the scene was more chaos, enchantingly so.  (From ACT)

Why adverb enchantingly is used here when it is modifying the subject "the scene"? I think enchanting would be more preferable.

Comment: _[...], enchanting so?_ No that's totally unidiomatic and ungrammatical. Also, _enchantingly_ is modifying the chaos within the scene, not the scene itself.

Comment: Don't get too hung up on the difference between (noun) ***chaos*** and (adjective) ***chaotic*** here. Many native speakers would consider both words equally suitable for the cited context, and they wouldn't care one way or the other what "part of speech" they supposedly represent .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, it does imply that the scene was enchanting - however, the adverb refers specifically to the *chaotic* nature the scene.

It could have instead said:

> The scene was *enchantingly chaotic*.

So it was chaotic in an enchanting way.

---

There are other ways of expressing a similar idea, for example:

> The scene was enchanting and chaotic.

Arguably though, these are now separate qualities - the scene was enchanting *and* was chaotic, perhaps for different reasons. Your original example does a great job of linking the two.